# Is Changing My Home Directory Name Going to Mess Up Virtual Environments?

Tags: python, django, macos, virtualenv

I'm looking to change my mac's home directory name. On the OS I'm on it seems this is the way to do it: https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-3872

Does anyone know if changing the home directory and following those steps will mess up virtual environments I have setup for Django projects or any other places paths might occur for programming?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can mess up your virtualenvs, because `*-link` and `*.pth` files can contain full paths when your are in development.

You may also have problems with entry points...

Rebuilding a virtualenv ins't so hard...

You can take a look at: [What parts of a virtualenv need to be changed to relocate it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6820109/what-parts-of-a-virtualenv-need-to-be-changed-to-relocate-it)