# Export Python project from one PC to other

Tags: python, virtualenv

I would like to easily export one Python project from one PC to other. When I created the project, I used a virtual environment in order to avoid problems with different package versions.

What I did was to just copy the project folder and paste it in the destination PC. Once I opened the project with Pycharm, I activated the virtual environment with project_path/venv/Scripts/activate, but when I tried to execute any Script, it said it didn´t find the modules.

Which is the workflow I should follow in order to create projects and be able to run them from multiple PC-s without needing to install all the dependencies?

Comment: What are the versions of python? These should be at least the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What parts of a virtualenv need to be changed to relocate it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6820109/what-parts-of-a-virtualenv-need-to-be-changed-to-relocate-it)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvirtualenv%5D+relocate

Comment: Virtualenvs aren't relocatable. Freeze the list of packages at the source venv, create a new destination venv and reinstall the packages.

Comment: I use Python 3.7 on Windows, but I have Python 3.6 also installed.

Answer (score 4):

Since you did not specify your Python version I will provide a solution working for both Python 2.x and 3.x.

My suggestion is to create a requirements.txt file containing all your requirements.

This file can be easily prepared using the output from the command:
`pip freeze`

Then you can paste the output in your requirements.txt file and when you are going to install your Python code on another PC you can simply:
`pip install -r requirements.txt`

To install your requirements again.

Depending on your project it could be possible, for example, to create a single EXE file (if you are using Windows machines) but more detailed is needed if this is the case.

In case you are using Python 3 the method that is at the moment arguably more popular in the Python community is Pipenv.

Here's its [relevant documentation](https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/en/latest/).

And here you can read a [simple example](https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/en/latest/basics/#example-pipenv-workflow) of a workflow.

Comment: I use Python 3.7 on Windows.

Comment: Hi @binflo13 I have updated my answer with details specifically Python 3 related.

Please upvote it and / or choose it as final answer if it was useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using python3 then use pipenv. It will automatically create `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock`. That will insure reinstalling dependencies on different machine will have the same packages.

basic and helpful commands:

- `pipenv shell`  # activate virutalenv
- `pipenv install`  # will install dependencies in `Pipfile`
- `pipenv install requests`  # will install requests lib. and will auto update `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock`